# Is there any file compression program that supports saving session and resuming when files become inaccessible?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, backup, file-transfer, compression

I intend to make one-time backup of ca. 100GB files from NAS. Unfortunately, due to poor design, the backup machine is limited to wireless access with the NAS. I expect the connection to break multiple times during the backup process; moreover, it is possible that I will need to reboot the backup machine.

Is there any tool that would have the following features:

- Resuming backing up process connection when the link with the remote share is unexpectedly severed
- Pausing and saving the session so the backup process can be resumed later (after reboot)
- aggressive compression of the files (at least on the level of zip)

I know that I can simply copy the files without compressing them with the help of file operation manager like [SuperCopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/supercopier.html), which has first two features.

AFAIK Popular compression programs: WinRar and 7zip don't support this saving sessions.

The backup machine runs Windows XP, but it can run Ubuntu/Mint as VM guest as well, so I'll accept solution from either world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `rsync`. It's fast, offers compression, and doesn't care at all about resuming the backup after some time. Doesn't restart automatically, but I'm not sure if you require that. Works on linux, or there are some windows versions I believe.

Checkout the manpage and examples online for usage.

Comment: I don't have rsync on the other server side, so the compression wouldn't help me. At the moment I've made a workaround: I copy the files with rsync into btrfs-compressed partition. But it doesn't solve my initial problem, since it requires a dedicated filesystem that supports compression.